# is it possible to block an exe running before it reaches UAC on win 10

Tags: windows-10, process, uac, blacklist

Foxit pdf keeps wanting to connect to some useless service via the exe which is shown by uac below ( attached not enough street cred ).

[image: uac warning]

is it possible to blacklist any exe from even trying to start even though its probably getting called from Process.Start by its parent program.

Comment: Move the file and see what happens. You will probably get error 2 - *The system cannot find the file specified.*

Comment: You can disable this from within Foxit Reader, or uninstall, reinstall, custom and not install that part too.

Comment: Also, you can specify any exe to not launch or launch another process through the registry, but this can break windows.

Comment: Change the compatibility mode of the `.exe` file to the earliest possible windows version. Depending on the `.exe` it goes all the way back to Windows 98.

Comment: @ user1292580 worked a treat, just deleted it the ex gets soaked up no more drramas.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Controlled folder access`

Controlled folder access in Windows Security reviews the apps that can make changes to files in protected folders and blocks unauthorized or unsafe apps from accessing or changing files in those folders.

Select `Start`  > `Settings`  > `Update & Security`  > `Windows Security` > `Virus & threat protection`.

Under Virus & threat protection settings, select Manage settings.

Under Controlled folder access, select Manage Controlled folder access.

Switch the Controlled folder access setting to `On` or `Off`.

*Occasionally, an app that is safe to use will be identified as harmful. This happens because Microsoft wants to keep you safe and will sometimes err on the side of caution; however, this might interfere with how you normally use your PC. You can add an app to the list of safe or allowed apps to prevent them from being blocked.*

[[Source]](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/allow-an-app-to-access-controlled-folders-b5b6627a-b008-2ca2-7931-7e51e912b034)

Comment: that still gives a prompt doesnt it, i was trying do get rid of the annoying prompts and just stop the program from even trying to be loaded, which deleting the exe did, and the program still functioned.

Comment: Have you tried with disabling UAC (never notify) ?